# PatternFill entire row openpyxl

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

I have an excel file that I have brought in as a df. I would like to highlight entire rows based off of names. So far, I am able to highlight only one column, but I would like the highlight applied to all columns. This is what I have so far, it runs through each name and applies a highlight color to it, after the name is no longer found, it moves on to the next name and applies the second highlight color, etc.

```
alist= df['NAME'].unique()
colorlist = ['efde6b','f4848d','bdbcff','75b56a','fcd7bd','f4b7c7','f79b74','a7d4f2']
count = 0
for a in alist:
    color = colorlist[count]
    color = str(color)
    for row in ws.iter_rows(1):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == a:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=color,
                                            end_color=color,
                                            fill_type='solid')
     count = count + 1
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
alist = test['NAME'].unique()
colorlist = ['efde6b','f4848d','bdbcff','75b56a','fcd7bd','f4b7c7','f79b74','a7d4f2']
count = 0
for a in alist:
    color = colorlist[count]
    color = str(color)
    for row in ws.iter_rows(1):
        for c in row:
            if c.value == a:
                row = c.row
                col = 1
                # print(row, col)
                while col < 9:
                    ws.cell(row=row, column=col).fill = PatternFill(start_color=color,
                                                    end_color=color,
                                                    fill_type='solid')
                    col = col + 1
```

Comment: This doesn't provide any kind of explanation and doesn't look much different.